# while in c++ to count geomatric series

Tags: c++, while-loop, line

How to count this, using while ?

1/(1 × 1) − 1/(2 × 2) + 1/(3 × 3) − 1/(4 × 4) + 1/(5 × 5) − ⋯
this line going to infinity so we cant count it, then we give the limit that the number below 10e-6 was ignored

Comment: I guess by writing proper code, compiling and executing.

Comment: and what is the code ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your homework for you. I will point you in the direction of a solution.

```
const double epsilon = 1e-6;
double term = 1.0, result = 0.0, x;

x = 1.0 / (term * term);
while (x > epsilon) {
  // rest of code here
}
```